# Setting multiple variables on button @click

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to do multiple things within button click (using Vuetify framework):

```
<v-btn flat color="indigo darken-3" 
@click.stop="dialogDelete = true"  
@click.stop="deleteTemporaryId = offer.id">Delete</v-btn>
```

But it seems wrong, I've got an error:

```
duplicate attribute: @click.stop
```

Anyone knows how to write correctly in Vuejs? Can I ask also multiple functions on @click?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use one method

```
<v-btn @click.stop="setDeleteDialog(offer.id)"

methods: {
  setDeleteDialog (offerId) {
    this.dialogDelete = true
    this.deleteTemporaryId = offerId
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use arrow function for @click.stop:

```
@click.stop="()=>{dialogDelete = true; deleteTemporaryId = offer.id}"
```

Comment: This should not be encouraged. To this type of things its way better to use a `method` to handle the logic.

Comment: @tiagojpdias agree. For simple function, it's ok. For complex one, it's better to create a new method.

Comment: I will follow the method solution

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old and perhaps not previously possible, but for anyone landing here now, this can be achieved without an arrow function, i.e.:

```
@click.stop="dialogDelete = true; deleteTemporaryId = offer.id"
```